# nodejs with mongodb: insert/find callbacks not running

Tags: node.js, mongodb

here is my model code to insert some records. On my work pc it works perfectly, but when I'm running it on my home pc with the same OS, collection.insert doesn't running its callback, so I get just long request which ends with time out. There are no errors, mongo db logs say "Connection accepted" 5 times, and after that there are no messages. The same happens when I try to fetch objects from database using find(). Inserting records with mongo shell works great, but with node.js I couldn't accomplish that.

```
/*
 * POST populate locations.
 */

var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient,
    _ = require('underscore'),
    env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development',
    config = require('../config/config')[env]

exports.connect = function(cb) {
    MongoClient.connect(config.db, function(err, db) {
        if (err) throw err;
        cb(db)
    });
}

exports.populate = function(data, cb) {
    var self = this;
    self.connect(function(db) {
        var collection = db.collection('locations');
        collection.insert(data, function(err, docs) {
            collection.ensureIndex({
                "loc": "2dsphere"
            }, function() {
                db.close();
                cb();
            });
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Try checking if there's some err with: collection.insert(data, function(err, docs) { throw err;

Comment: collection.insert callback not running at all, so there is no way to output anything from there

Comment: The code should make one connection to the DB and keep it. You could store it within the module. Then, use that within the populate method. Also, I don't know why you'd insert data and then call `ensureIndex`?

Comment: for this example there is one connection, and there is no metter what code is in callback function since callback itself not running.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
exports.populate = function(data, cb) {
    MongoClient.connect(config.db, function(db) {
        var collection = db.collection('locations');
        collection.insert(data, function(err, docs) {
            collection.ensureIndex({
                "loc": "2dsphere"
            }, function() {
                db.close();
                cb();
            });
        });
    });
}
```